# How can I ensure that a message will be given to a specific consumer in a queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

We are working in a microservice architecture and we are using RabbitMQ as a message broker. We want to avoid the scenarios where the following happens:

1. An entity begins its creation but it takes a while for it to finish.
2. The system decides that the creation time has taken too long and that the entity should be deleted due to a timeout, so it sends out a message to delete the entity which is currently still being created
3. Delete message gets consumed and the system checks whether the entity exists and does not find it due to the entity still being in the process of being created.
4. Delete entity message consumer returns an error due to not finding the entity.

How can we ensure that the `delete` message is consumed after the `create` message is finished in such a way that we do not block the consumption of other messages?

Answer (score 2):

> How can we ensure that the delete message is consumed after the create message is finished in such a way that we do not block the consumption of other messages?

Let's say your entity creation timeout is N. The worker(s) responsible for creating entities should know about this timeout, and should be able to cancel entity creation should N be reached. This isn't strictly necessary but it sounds like your entity creation may be resource intensive so cancellation should be a feature you have.

If your workers know to cancel entity creation when timeout N is reached, then perhaps you don't even need the deletion message?

If you keep the delete message, the workers processing that could do the following:

- First, ensure your queue has a [Dead Letter Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) configured
- Consume the message, and try to delete the entity
- If deletion succeeds, great, ack the message with RabbitMQ and you're done
- If deletion fails, *nack* (reject) the message with RabbitMQ and do set `requeue` to be `false`. This will cause the message to be routed to the dead-letter exchange
- A worker should consume from a queue bound to this dead-letter exchange. You could have a queue dedicated to re-trying entity deletions. When a worker consumes a message from this queue, it can re-try the deletion. If it fails, you can reject it again (after a delay, of course) and, if this queue has the same dead-letter settings, the same process will happen
- Finally, ensure that your deletion workers respect the `count` property and only try a certain number of times to delete an entity. If a limit is exceeded, this should create an exception in your system